# How can I support Core Data in iOS 7 and iOS 8 with namespacing?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift

I would like to support both iOS 7 and iOS 8 if possible. I am writing the app in Swift. When setting up Core Data, I found out that you have to namespace your classes in your data model. Otherwise the class isn't found (i.e. Target.Class vs Class). Requiring a namespace here is an issue for a couple of reasons. One, it means you can't use your data model in different targets (including testing targets), and two, it breaks in the opposite direction in iOS 7. iOS 7 looks for Class but the data model now has Target.Class.

Does anyone know the appropriate way to support both iOS 7 and iOS 8 in this situation? I've run into other areas where the namespacing has caused issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the @objc tag to your custom class declaration will have the additional affect of moving it into the default namespace, which has no mangling so is usable from both iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: Which should not be taken to imply that you need to use @objc on all classes for iOS 7 compatibility, it's only necessary for those classes that are referred to by string name, most likely from CoreData, Nib files, or with NSCoding.

Comment: I take this to mean "@objc class MyClass..." instead of "class MyClass..." but that will get overwritten anytime I regenerate Core Data model classes. Am I missing an option for this within the xcdatamodel so that it does this when generating those classes?

Comment: How are you generating them?

Comment: Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass... and then selecting the files I've updated. Although it seems like it only works now if I delete the previous files.

Comment: Yeah, that's only useful for one-time generation, especially since you lose any customizations you make to the generated code.  You might want to take a look at mogenerator.  I pretty much don't do core data without it any more.

Comment: I actually had someone else recommend that today as well. I'll check that out tomorrow. I'm going to test the @objc suggestion as well and accept the answer if it works as expected.